# Communicate with device on different subnet (router changes only)

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have a MikroTik router, and two other devices on the network, A and B:
MikroTik router: 192.168.**133.1/22**
device A: 192.168.**133.160/22**, port 2 (LAN)
device B: 192.168.**100.1/24**, port 3 (LAN)

I would like device A to be able to reach device B.

I have tried under IP->Firewall->NAT to add a rule with the settings: srcnat (chain), src Address (192.168.133.160), action (src-nat) and To Addresses (192.168.100.102), along with numerous other configurations, however I have been unable to get any pingable response from device B.

All the router needs to do is mask device A's IP in packets going to device B, and device B's IP in packets going to device A. Seems like such a simple task to just replace some bytes in the header packets, but alas, I have gotten nowhere. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/860949/communicating-with-devices-on-a-different-subnet) was similar, but they were able to change their device IPs, which I cannot.

How should the router be configured to achieve this?
Note the devices A and B cannot have their configurations changed. The ports can be changed, eg one device B could be moved to the WAN port 1.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: 1) Have you verified with /tool/sniffer that the router really _isn't_ replacing the addresses? 2) Are the two ports part of the same bridge or are they independent? 3) What makes src-nat necessary in your situation at all?